# How to generate code stub in WebStorm editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, code-generation, stub

I am using WebStorm IDE for nodejs development. Whenever I write a new test case. First, try to create the following stub

```
describe('', ()=>{
    it('', ()=>{

    });
});
```

and then complete the test logic.
How can I save the above stub somewhere in the IDE and get pasted/generated at the cursor by some key shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your code snippet in editor, then choose **Save as Live Template...** from **Tools** main menu. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html#9f697662

see also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/using-live-templates.html

Comment: Great help. Just made my day.